# Ошибка 'str' object is not callable [PYTHON]

Tags: python, telebot, строки

Пишу бота, столкнулся с этой ошибкой. Не могу понять в чем проблема, ошибка выходит на этапе регистрации, но именно на повторной, т.е если запустить бота и зарегистрироваться, то ошибки не будет, но при смене аккаунта и повторной регистрации в этом месте происходит ошибка...

```
    number_vu = '' # Тут во-избежание заполненных переменных с прошлой регистрации, решил чистить перед новой.
    number_sts = ''
    number_car = ''
    name = ''

    message = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите свое имя.")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_name)
    def reg_name(message):
                  global name
                  name = message.text
                  answer = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 
                                    "Введите гос.номер вашего авто!") 
                  bot.register_next_step_handler(answer, number_car) # ошибка на этом этапе.

   def number_car(message):
                 global number_car
                 number_car = message.text
                 bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите серию и номер вашего СТС")
                 bot.register_next_step_handler(message, number_sts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите гос.номер вашего авто!") 
bot.register_next_step_handler(message, number_car)
```

Comment: Изначально так и стояло, это не работает(

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py примеры из telebot